# How to remove a table from cache in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, ddl, alter-table

I tried to add a table to cache in Oracle

```
alter table Test_Table cache;
```

So now how can I remove it from cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
alter table Test_Table NOCACHE;
```

But be aware that using the cache doesn't actually pin the table in cache. It just tells oracle to handle the blocks differently once they get there. Tom Kyte has a good explanantion on [this.](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:253415112676)

Answer (score 1):

The counterpart of `cache` is `nocache`:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table NOCACHE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to run the same command with `nocache` instead:

```
alter table Test_Table nocache;
```